# PHP Session sharing

Tags: php, session, session-cookies

We use WHMCS for our billing system for our hosting business. WHMCS is written in PHP. As usual, there is the usual login box which reads the DB etc,etc,etc.

We wish to develop a seperate system to let our customers manage their servers with us (non-billing related things). Is it possible to let the customer loging to WHMCS as usual, then somehow "magically" be allowed access to the new system portal?

Please keep in mind that WHMCS isn't open source so I can't touch this code, however I can run them on the same Apache instance. Also, of course, I'd like to keep security in mind.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of how you'd do so:

```
<?php
require("whmcs/dbconnect.php"); // You may have to change the path here
if ($_SESSION['uid']) {
    echo "whmcs user logged in";
} else {
    echo "whmcs user not yet login";
}
?>
```

Comment: Can you please explain why I need dbconnect.php? Also, does $_SESSION['uid'] just check to see if uid is set? Do I not need isset?

Comment: dbconnect.php should be your WHMCS dbconnect.php file. They have their own code to create/validate a session, so including that file and utilizing the $_SESSION['uid'] is the simplest method of finding out whether a user is logged in, and acquiring their UID if you need to use it in your own database. The $_SESSION['uid'] should be returned as null if the user is not logged in, so no need to use isset() (although if that makes you more comfortable go for it).

Comment: Excellent! Thanks for your help! I guess I'm still a bit confused why I need their dbconnect.php? If I didn't include that file, would their session vars not be accessable? Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure if you can leave out the dbconnect.php file, as it's encrypted and whatnot with a special loader so I have no detailed idea of what it does. Every example I've seen though uses the file, so worst case scenario you can leave it out and just find out if the page works ;) Though it's very handy if you need to grab any client details since it includes the connection information for WHMCS.

Comment: Slight issue: Once a user logs in, and then logs out, uid seems to be still set... Any ideas?

Comment: Ok, i fixed my above issue by checking to see if uid > 0, as when someone logs out, it's still set but set at "nothing". Is everything above secure? Do I need to take any other measure to prevent session hijacking, or will the WHMCS guys have handled that and I'm inheriting their security? Thanks

Comment: I would hope that the WHMCS sessions are secure seeing as most of it works over SSL and deals with monetary transactions. You shouldn't have any issues with session hijacking though that you could fix, any security issues that crop up should be solved by WHMCS (unless you're modifying the session information in some way of course).

Comment: Excellent. Thanks for your help. What I intend to do is use this uid to query the WHMCS database directly to get other bits of information. However it's good to know that the session stuff will be handled by WHMCS by a simple check of $_SESSION['uid']. Thanks